# Leave TabActivity and return to it properly

Tags: android, tabactivity, activitygroup

I have an issue where I have an ActivityGroup using TabActivities. Everything works great switching between different activities. However, I have some views that I don't want to have tabs.  They are completely different views I don't want to be part of the activity group.

Currently I'm leaving the activity group by just doing a regular `startActivity(intent)` in the `ActivityGroup`'s `startActivityFromChild` function.

This works, but when I hit the back button, though I return to the previous TabActivity, `onCreate()` is called twice as a result.

How can I properly leave a `TabActivity` to a regular `Activity` then properly go back to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. The issue had to do with  getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(newRecord.id, newRecord.intent); being called twice in the activity group in different functions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but I bet onCreate is being called twice intentionally.  Perhaps once by the Group and then by the actual Tab.  Is this behavior actually breaking your code?

Perhaps move to a separate function the code that you don't want to run twice.  Then set a flag to decide if/when you want to run it.

```
public class YourActivity {

    private boolean i_feel_like_it = true;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            runIfYouFeelLikeIt();
    }


    private void runIfYouFeelLikeIt() {
        if(i_feel_like_it) {
             doIt();
             i_feel_like_it = false;
        }
    }
}
```